# How do I convert a Time.parse("October 4 1984") into a ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, activesupport

I am using Chronic to parse time and it is returning this error:

```
ArgumentError in EventsController#create 

comparison of Date with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone failed
```

This is because since Rails 2.1 the database and Ruby are on different timezones.

How can I convert my statement to work ?

```
def set_dates
  unless self.natural_date.blank? || Chronic.parse(self.natural_date).blank?
    # check if we are dealing with a date or a date + time
    if time_provided?(self.natural_date)
      self.date = nil
      self.time = Chronic.parse(self.natural_date)
    else
      self.date = Chronic.parse(self.natural_date).to_date
      self.time = nil
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time.zone` has a `parse` method, which also returns a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`:

```
>> Time.zone.parse "October 4 1984"
=> Thu, 04 Oct 1984 00:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

To get it playing with Chronic, maybe [this article](http://mad.ly/2008/09/25/making-rails-time-zone-aware-attributes-and-chronic-play-well-together/) can help? If you were to, for instance, patch a `parse_with_chronic` method into `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`, then you could rewrite your method:

```
def set_dates
  unless self.natural_date.blank? || Time.zone.parse_with_chronic(self.natural_date).blank?
    # check if we are dealing with a date or a date + time
    if time_provided?(self.natural_date)
      self.date = nil
      self.time = Time.zone.parse_with_chronic(self.natural_date)
    else
      self.date = Time.zone.parse_with_chronic(self.natural_date).to_date
      self.time = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: True, but it doesn't really help me figure out how to make `Chronic.parse(self.natural_date).to_date` to become an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

Comment: That patch was actually the way to go. I tried the other answer and it failed after I had marked it correct. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) has a constructor, which takes a normal Time object in utc and a timezone. So, given time is you can try this:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.new(Chronic.parse(self.natural_date).utc, Time.zone)
```

Comment: Actually this didn't quite work. The above patch seemed to save the day. Thanks so much Baju